# Conditional Type splits "function returning boolean" into "function returning true unions function returning false"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In Typescript, Conditional Type splits "function returning boolean" `() => boolean` into "function returning true unions function returning false" `() => true | () => false`.

Could anyone explain why, and any solution to keep its returning type as "boolean"?

Example:

```js
type A<U, E> = U extends E ? () => U : () => U;
const a: A<boolean, string> = () => Math.random() < 0.5;
```

Compile Error:

```
TS2322: Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type '(() => false) | (() => true)'.
   Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type '() => false'.
     Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.
```

Comment: Apparently `boolean` is internally represented as a union `true | false`. In conditional types if you are checking if some type is assignable to a union, typescript will map over this union. Basically `X extends A | B ? ... : ...` is equivalent to `(X extends A ? ... : ...) | (X extends B ? ... : ...)`. To prevent this mapping you can do for example `[U] extends [E]` instead of `U extends E`. This way `[E]` is not a union (it is a tuple whose element is a union) and it doesn't get mapped, but `[U]` is assignable to `[E]` if and only if `U` is assignable to `E`, so the condition doesn't change

Comment: Impressive, this works! Thanks a lot!